# wxPython : Ubuntu Title Bar Icon not getting displayed

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to display an icon on the title bar of our application build using wxPython on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS box:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/05/23/wxpython-embedding-an-image-in-your-title-bar/

I tried all the ways described in the link but no icon comes up in the title bar? Is there any way for to achieve the same?

```
self.loc = wx.IconLocation(r'my.ico', 0)
#self.ico = wx.Icon('my.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
#self.SetIcon(self.ico)
self.SetIcon(wx.IconFromLocation(self.loc))
```

Comment: This works fine to me, [Try this](http://codepad.org/vu5djvda) to see if it's working.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but the icon still does not comes up in title bar - it is displayed when pressing Alt + Tab only